# Arrays crash with index over the first

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio

I have newly started with C++, but I keep ruining in to a pretty annoying problem. As soon as I use dynamic arrays I'm stuck. The array looks really messed up in debug (look picture) and as soon as I add more the one object to the array it crashes. This is not a error i get one specific project but all code that uses dynamic arrays, I even tried to compile the code made by the teacher in this course but no success. So it's not likely that it's the code that is the problem but probably something else. I did however include the test code i used to demonstrate this just to be safe.
[image: Debug of the code]

```
#include "iostream"
#include "string"
#include "Student.h"
int main()
{
    _CrtSetDbgFlag( _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
    string input;
    Student **students = NULL;
    students = new Student*[20];
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        students[i] = new Student();
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        delete students[i];
    }
    delete[] students;
    return 0;
}



#include "Student.h"
#include "string"

Student::Student()
{
    name = "";
    number = 0;
}
Student::Student(string Name)
{
    name = Name;
    number = 0;
}
Student::~Student()
{

}
string Student::getName() const
{
    return name;
}



#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H
#include "string"
#include "Course.h"
using namespace std;
class Student
{
private:
    string name;
    int number;
public:
    Student();
    Student(string Name);
    virtual ~Student();
    string getName() const;
};
#endif
```

Comment: I do not see you adding Students to the array.  Please update your question with how you are putting the Student objects into the array

Comment: You should really consider using `std::vector` or some other STL container.

Comment: Your test demonstrates that value pointed by NULL pointer can't be inspected. What's surprising in it?

Comment: @fontanini, that would be a great suggestion - if this wasn't a classroom environment. Learning the intricacies of pointers is valuable.

Comment: Are you saying the code given here crashes at some point? Please show the line it crashes on and what error message you get. I personally can't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: @frozen - It is not a crash, it is just the debugger saying  that it cannot show you any `student`s when all you have is NULL pointers.

Comment: Sorry was a little quick with posting the code, edit it now but the problem with only one item is still there.

Comment: @Frozendragon Curiosity, Have you tried doing this by not using a nested aliasing pointer? such as Student *students; students = new Students[20]; ?

Comment: @Frozendragon by using a ** pointer your trying to make a matrix of pointers. If this was your intent, then overlook my comments

Comment: @MarkRansom: Learning the intricacies of pointers is not at all valuable for a guy who cannot use `std::vector`. Why learn the vastly less effective and less useful solution, when you could learn an easier and much more effective solution?

Comment: @Frozendragon that code doesn't build because of `Student **students = new Student();`.  Other than that, it "works" fine for me.

Comment: @MarkRansom I didn't see the "homework" tag anywhere, nor does OP mention this is homework.

Comment: @fontanini Yea, but it does just scream "homework" doesn't it

Comment: @fontanini, quote: "the teacher in this course".

Comment: I can't see on your screenshot if you have `students[i] = new Student();` or `students[i] = NULL;` but clearly I can see that inspecting `students[0]` gives address `0x00000000` which is most common null pointer value. Anyway, what are the symptoms of a crash? Line of crash and error message please.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it looks messed up in the debugger is because you are attempting to view the *student* (which you have not yet allocated and thus the contents are appropriately invalid) not the array *students*. The debugger cannot show dynamically allocated arrays.

Also, `students = new Student();`? This shouldn't even *compile*, and the logic is beyond wrong. You're assigning a `Student*` to a `Student**`.

As a general rule, never, ever, use `new[]` in your own code.  Always use `std::vector`. Then you will automatically construct the correct number of `Student` classes, and will never leak memory or anysuch thing like that.

```
int main() {
    std::vector<Student> students;
    string input;
    students.resize(20);
    // Now you can use ALL THE STUDENTS
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i agree, but for some reason i think it's a class room setting. And i commented in his post about his matrix of pointers.

Comment: @johnathon: Being a classroom makes it *more* important that he uses `std::vector`, not less.

Comment: yea, well, trust me I've seen class room setting c++ , cs101 students homework, and trust me, the std and STL is no where in it.

Comment: @johnathon: That's because the C++ lecturer in that specific instutition is incompetent, not because it should be that way. My lecturer actually did teach `std::vector` first. Not that he actually taught much... but `std::vector` came first.

Comment: @DeadMG - I disagree.  I think if this is early days in the course, learning pointers and basics of memory management is vital.  `operator new` and `operator delete` are a fundamental part of the language, even if you can mostly forget about them once you know what they do.

Comment: @SteveTownsend: No, the basics of memory management is `std::vector`. `operator new` is the "OH MY GOD IT'S SO MUCH REPETITIVE POINTLESS EFFORT" of memory management. They are a fundamental part- of implementing `std::vector`. Nothing else. You don't need them except to implement your own memory managing classes, which no beginner needs to do.